# Estimation of Distribution using multiple ECDFs

Tags: estimation, cumulative-distribution-function, parameterization, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

Every day, I keep track of the processing times for each input to my CPU and create empirical cumulative distribution functions (ECDFs) based on this data. Let's assume I have 100 observations per day and I do this process for 10 days, resulting in 10 ECDFs each of which with 100 points. Now, the challenge is to estimate the underlying distribution of the data. What method or approach do you suggest?

To illustrate this, let's assume that the underlying distribution follows a normal distribution with a mean of 10, but with some noise. In other words, the underlying cumulative distribution function (CDF) for each day has a mean of 10 plus some noise. For the sake of discussion, let's assume that on colder days, the CPU works slightly slower, resulting in a higher mean processing time than 10. However, since we do not directly measure temperature or any external factor, we only observe this effect as noise in the data. The same situation applies to the standard deviation (sigma) of the underlying distribution. Please refer to the following Python code and figure for a visual representation.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# Generate random data from a normal distribution
np.random.seed(0)
n_samples = 100  # Number of samples
n_ecdfs = 10  # Number of ECDFs to generate
mu = 10  # Mean of the normal distribution
sigma = 1  # Standard deviation of the normal distribution



# Compute the ECDFs for each column in the data
ecdfs = []
for i in range(n_ecdfs):
    # I also change the mu and sigma the underlying distribution of each ecdf slightly 
    data = np.random.normal(mu+np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5), 
                            sigma+np.random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2), 
                            n_samples)
    x = np.sort(data)
    y = np.arange(1, n_samples + 1) / n_samples
    ecdf = np.column_stack((x, y))
    ecdfs.append(ecdf)

# Create plotly figure
fig = px.line(title='Empirical Cumulative Distribution Functions (ECDFs) from Normal Distribution')

# Add ECDF traces to the figure
for i in range(n_ecdfs):
    fig.add_scatter(x=ecdfs[i][:, 0], y=ecdfs[i][:, 1], mode='lines', name=f'ECDF {i + 1}')

# Set x-axis label
fig.update_xaxes(title_text='X')

# Set y-axis label
fig.update_yaxes(title_text='ECDF')

# Show plot
fig.show()
```

[image]

P.S: Definitely one approach can be to put them all together and draw an ecdf and try to fit a cdf to it. However, I am very curious to know if there is another approach.

Comment: Could you please explain why it doesn't suffice to combine all your datasets into one and use that for the distributional estimate?  If it's because of the suspected effect of other factors, then you have a different question, because there isn't one distribution: it's either a *regression* problem, amounting to finding how the distribution varies with other *known* factors, or a question of estimating how the distribution varies with time -- something that could be made more precise by adopting parametric assumptions about the distribution and its time variation.

Comment: It's still unclear what your aim is, and by including that remark about correlation you indicate you aren't even working with random samples, which calls into question what your ECDFs might even mean.  It would be better for you to describe what you want to *achieve* rather than asking whether this particular way of going about it might somehow be used.